# ¿Cómo recuperar datos de una base de datos y insertarlos en un formulario? PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario conectado a una base de datos, funciona todo bien, pero cuando intento modificar algun registro enviando como dato el id no me ejecuta nada y salta el error(`PHP Warning:  mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`)

Adjunto mi código porque llevo horas probando donde puedo estar y no encuentro el fallo:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Clientes");
$id = $_GET['idCliente'];
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = ?")) {
    //bind del valor por GET a la consulta 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $mysqli->query($stmt);
}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";

                while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){
                echo"<html>";
                    echo"<head>";
                        echo"<title>Formulario SISRITEL</title>";
                        echo"<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
                        echo"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>";
                        echo"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/estilo.css'>";

                    echo"</head>";
                    echo"<body>";
                        echo"<div class='container'>";  
                        echo"<form id='contact' action='formulario.php' method='post' name='formulario'>";
                        echo"<h3>Añadir a la base de datos</h3>";
                        echo"<h4>Los campos con el asterisco son obligatorios</h4>";

                echo "<fieldset>";
                echo "    Nombre:<span class='obligatorio'>*</span>";
                echo "    <input placeholder='Nombre' type='text' tabindex='1' name='nombre' required autofocus value='<?php echo $row [0]; ?>'>";

                echo "    <button name='submit' type='submit' id='contact-submit' data-submit='Enviando...'>Enviar</button>";
                echo "</fieldset>";
                echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</body>";
    echo " </html>";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: estas usando un ORM?

Comment: Estás duplicando procedimientos. Cuando se usan consultas preparadas, no se usa `query` como veo que haces aquí: `$result = $mysqli->query($stmt);` debes borrar esa línea, porque **la consulta se ejecuta en el método `execute`** en este caso. `query` es para consultas no preparadas. Como consecuencia de ello, al leer los datos, **debes aplicar el método `fetch_row` al objeto `$stmt`**, que será el que apuntará a los datos. O sea, esto debe ser corregido así: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row()){ `, actualmente, usas la variable `$result`.

Comment: @A.Cedano siguiendo tus pasos me salta otro erro `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row()` con el `while ($row = $stmt->fetch_row())`

Comment: Ufff sí, estamos ante el eterno dolor de cabeza de MySQLi... ¡Hay que asignar los resultados a variables! ¿Podrías decirme cómo se llaman las columnas que quieres obtener en tu consulta y corrijo la respuesta? Si sabes las columnas la cosa se complica, a no ser que tengas un driver que no sé si tienes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores en el código

### Error 1

Estás duplicando procedimientos.

Cuando se usan consultas preparadas, **no se usa `query`** como veo que haces aquí: <s>`$result = $mysqli->query($stmt);`</s> debes borrar esa línea, porque la consulta se ejecuta en el método `execute` en este caso.

**`query` se usa cuando estamos trabajando con consultas no preparadas**.

### Error 2

Hay otro error que es consecuencia del primero: al leer los datos, debes aplicar el método de lectura al objeto `$stmt`, que será el que apuntará a los datos, y no a `$result`, como está ahora: <s>`while ($row = $result->fetch_row()){`</s>

### Error 3 : ¡El eterno dolor de cabeza de mysqli y una de las razones por las que no uso esta API!

Leer nuestros datos en una consulta preparada con mysqli es un verdadero dilema, a no ser que contemos con el driver `mysqlnd` el cual cuenta con un método `get_result`. La cuestión es que no hay forma de almacenar los datos en ninguna parte para recorrerlos.<sup>1</sup>

Entonces:

- Tienes que indicar explícitamente tus columnas en el `SELECT`
- Tienes que recurrir a `bind_result` para asignar una variable a cada columna del `SELECT`
- Tienes que aplicar el método `fetch`  al `$stmt` para leer los resultados.

El código quedaría entonces así.

Si sigue sin funcionar, revisa tu consulta y depura la variable `$id = $_GET['idCliente'];` que estás pasando como criterio.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "Clientes");
$id = $_GET['idCliente'];
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Nombre, Direccion, Telefono FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = ?")) {
    //bind del valor por GET a la consulta 
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $stmt->execute(); /*La consulta se ejecuta aquí*/
    //$result = $mysqli->query($stmt); <------ /*Esto sobra*/

    $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $direccion, $telefono);

}
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";

                while ($stmt->fetch()){ /*aplicamos fetch a $stmt para recorrerlo*/
                echo"<html>";
                    echo"<head>";
                        echo"<title>Formulario SISRITEL</title>";
                        echo"<meta charset='UTF-8'>";
                        echo"<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>";
                        echo"<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/estilo.css'>";

                    echo"</head>";
                    echo"<body>";
                        echo"<div class='container'>";  
                        echo"<form id='contact' action='formulario.php' method='post' name='formulario'>";
                        echo"<h3>Añadir a la base de datos</h3>";
                        echo"<h4>Los campos con el asterisco son obligatorios</h4>";

                echo "<fieldset>";
                echo "    Nombre:<span class='obligatorio'>*</span>";
                echo "    <input placeholder='Nombre' type='text' tabindex='1' name='nombre' required autofocus value='<?php echo $nombre; ?>'>";

                echo "    <button name='submit' type='submit' id='contact-submit' data-submit='Enviando...'>Enviar</button>";
                echo "</fieldset>";
                echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</body>";
    echo " </html>";
}
    ?>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> En otra pregunta que anda por esta red, existe una función que simula a `get_result`. Es otra alternativa, si por algún motivo no puedes usar PDO en vez de mysqli. Es la API que recomiendo, por ser más robusta y por facilitar las cosas enormemente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, después de hacer este paso me sale PHP `Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_row()` hay algún fallo en porque no me reconoce el método con el $result y no con el $stmt

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez, aquí: `SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE Nombre = ?` en vez del `*` hay que indicar los nombres de columnas que quieres, y luego hay que hacer un `bind_result` que almacene cada valor de las columnas a una variable. Es un verdadero escollo de mysqli  :(  Para usar `fetch_row` tendrías primero que hacer un `get_result`, pero el problema es que `get_result` está en un driver aparte y no sé si tu servidor lo tendrá instalado. Si me pones un `SELECT`  con los nombres de columna que quieres en el resultado editaré la respuesta con un código que funcione.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por tu tiempo de antemano. Es la primera vez que me pongo con mysqli porque me dijeron que mysql era vulnerable a inyecciones sql, quisiera obtener los campos (Nombre, Direccion, Telefono)

Comment: Listo @AlbertoMartínez, revisa el nuevo código. Observa que hay cambios, he agregado un `bind_result`, y el `while` cambia también, así como este `input` donde imprimes el nombre: `<input placeholder='Nombre' type='text' tabindex='1' name='nombre' required autofocus value='<?php echo $nombre; ?>'>`  No vi dónde usabas los campos `Nombre`y `Direccion`. Si quieres imprimir sus valores, echa mano de las variables `$nombre` y  `$direccion`, que fue las que se declararon en el `bind_result`.

Comment: Las utilizo en mi código, pero como es igual que nombre lo quité para hacer mas fácil la lectura. Muchas gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez de nada. Y si estás empezando y debes decidir por una API segura para manejar la base de datos, `mysqli` lo es, pero es mucho más complicada que PDO, sobre todo con las consultas preparadas. Yo te recomendaría que uses PDO en vez de mysqli. Te lo comento para que lo tengas en cuenta. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, me pondré a leer para tenerlo en cuenta el próximo paso que haga.